# How to fix error reading 'node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga/yoga/log.cpp' React Native

Tags: xcode, react-native

Hope anyone can help me I get this error when I am building react native for the ios app in Xcode. How can fix it?
error: error reading '/Users/nathim/Desktop/kongvengheng/node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga/yoga/log.cpp'
1 error generated.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I was facing the same issue with the newer version of Xcode. I fixed it by giving full disk access to Xcode.

For `macOS`, go to `System Preferences` > `Security & Privacy` and select `Privacy` tab.

Give `Full Disk Access` to `Xcode` as shown in the screenshot below.
[image]